# How to solve this circular dependency issue with functions taking structs?

Tags: c, emulation, sdl-2

I'm trying to solve an issue with a function in one header requiring a structure as a parameter that includes the structure from the same header as the function. Here is the code:

#### Nintendo.h

```
/**
 * Nintendo.h - Nintendo Entertainment System
 * 
 * This header file is the struct that cotains every component of our
 * Ninetendo Entertainment System. This is the core file, so to speak,
 * that brings together components such as the CPU, PPU, and APU, along
 * with some other smaller components.
 */

#ifndef _NINTENDO_H
#define _NINTENDO_H

#include "Registers.h"

typedef struct Nintendo
{
    Registers reg;
} Nintendo;

#endif /* _NINTENDO_H */
```

#### Registers.h

```
#ifndef _REGISTERS_H
#define _REGISTERS_H

#include "Constants.h"
#include "Nintendo.h"

typedef struct Registers
{
    /* Special Purpose Registers */
    Uint16 pc;  /* Program Counter */
    Uint8  sp;  /* Stack Pointer */

    /* Bit 7 - Negative Flag        N
       Bit 6 - Overflow Flag        V
       Bit 5 - Unused
       Bit 4 - Break Command        B
       Bit 3 - Decimal Mode         D
       Bit 2 - Interrupt Disable    I
       Bit 1 - Zero Flag            Z
       Bit 0 - Carry Flag           C
    */
    Uint8  p;   /* Processor Status */

    /* General Purpose Registers */
    Uint8  a;   /* Accumulator */
    Uint8  x;
    Uint8  y;

} Registers;

void InitializeRegisters(Nintendo *nes);

#endif /* _REGISTERS_H */
```

As you can see, the 'InitializeRegisters' function takes a Nintendo structure as an argument, but that Nintendo structure includes the Registers structure in its definition. This is causing circular dependency problems.

I know I can solve this by making the parameter take Registers* and just pass &Nintendo.reg, but I'd rather not do that.

Here is the error output:

```
In file included from source/Nintendo.h:13:
source/Registers.h:31:26: error: unknown type name 'Nintendo'
void InitializeRegisters(Nintendo *nes);
                         ^
1 error generated.
In file included from source/Registers.h:5:
source/Nintendo.h:17:5: error: unknown type name 'Registers'
    Registers reg;
    ^
1 error generated.
/bin/ld: /bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:2: test] Error 1
```

Comment: Why does the function called`InitialiseRegisters` take a `Nintendo` struct at all? Why not a `Registers *` as the name implies?

Comment: Well you have to define Registers, then Nintendo, then InitializeRegisters.

Comment: Unrelated re your comment: The orignal Nintendo CPU certainly  did not have general purpose registers; all were very specialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer is to add the line:

```
typedef struct Nintendo Nintendo;
```

near the top of registers.h ( using mixed case for header files is a very bad idea ).   A characteristic of C is that typedef statements may be repeated provided they are all consistent, and serve as a "forward declaration", which is what you require.

If you wanted to be perverse, you could put it in nintendo.h above the #ifndef line, but there are other ways to get your jollies if that is your thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just wondering, why is mixed case for headers bad?

Comment: That's bad advice, working around a bad program architecture.

Comment: @ConnerTurmon: It is not, that's just a singular opinion. Actually it's pretty common if CamelCase or mixedCase is used. Also see my comment above.

Comment: Header files are fundamentally an external, or system provided construct.  DOS and Windows made the stunningly stupid decision to ignore case in the file system;  MacOS followed suit.   Once they discovered the error, they made worse decisions about it, so that sometimes x.h matched X.H and other times it didn't.   The end result is, don't used mixed case because you cannot depend upon the decisions of the people who make the operating systems you depend upon.   They just aren't that smart.